# How to handle spaces in values if you use spaces as a delimiter with regex?

Tags: java, regex

I'm attempting to run a regex to capture the key and value of the following string:

`name="Evoke Sprite" parent="EvokeObjects" instance=ExtResource( 5 ) id=5`

Here are some syntax notes for each are as follows:

- Keys: a string of letters, no spaces
- Values:

  - May have quotation marks eg. "EvokeObjects"
  - May have spaces within the quotation marks
  - May have special characters within the quotation marks eg "hello/world@!18"
  - May have a function like string ("ExtResource( 5 )").
  - The function string will have spaces within the brackets

I've gotten as far as having spaces within quotes with this:

`(.*?)=(?:"(.*?)"|(.*?))(?: |$)`

So this will work with
`name="Evoke Sprite" parent="EvokeObjects" id=5`

regex101 to test: https://regex101.com/r/xkRRsD/1

The problem occurs when I add the `ExtResource( 5 )` because it has the space within the brackets. Then the previous regex code fails.

As a possible workaround I was thinking maybe I could remove the spaces altogether from the brackets by doing a string replace in code. But I was wondering if there was a regex solution to this?

Comment: *"a string of text, no spaces"* Do you mean a string of *characters*, or a string of *letters*? Either way. `.*?` is not it, because that includes spaces.

Comment: If input is `#$%^=*@( !<>)` is that a valid key `#$%^` / value `*@( !<>)` combination?

Comment: can you have string string with space as value without `"`   i.e `key=some value some random value`

Comment: @CodeManiac In this case If it needs spaces it will have quotation marks so I wont have to worry about that case.

Comment: @Andreas It will most likely be only letters. There wont be any special characters, and there wont be any numbers. For the value the string with quotation can have special characters eg `"hello/world@!"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the second part of the alternation, you match until a space or the end of the string so that would match `ExtResource(`

What you could do is either match not a parenthesis or match from an opening till a closing parenthesis.

Instead of using non greedy quantifiers, you might use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated).

```
([^=\s]+)=(?:"([^"]+)"|((?:[^\s()"]|\([^()]*\))+))
```

**Explanation**

- `([^=]+)=` Capture group 1, match any char except `=`, then match `=`
- `(?:` Non capturing groups

  - `"([^"]*)"` Match ", then capture any char except " in group 2, then match "
  - `|` Or
  - `(` Capture group 3

    - `(?:` Non capturing group

      - `[^\s()"]` Match any char except `(`, `)`, `"` or a whitespace char
      - `|` Or
      - `\([^()]*\)` Match from opening till closing parenthesis
    - `)+` Close non capturing group and repeat 1+ times
  - `)` Close group 3
- `)` Close non capturing group

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lP0LDT/1)

Comment: @Andreas You are right, hank you. I have updated  it.

Comment: @Andreas Now it will match those as well.

Comment: Not sure if `a=` should match as key `a` with empty value. Nothing in the requirements preclude it. Your regex won't match that. But, changed my down-vote to up-vote anyway.

Comment: Thank you (and for you feedback). Lets wait for the OP to clarify that part and I will update it accordingly.

Comment: There wont be any null or empty values such as from `a=`. Thanks for helping me clarify.

Comment: This is great, I was thinking I may have to do some lookaheads but this is a simpler solution. I'll admit, I'm a tad unfamiliar with the negated character class but your clear explanation has helped me immensely.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: v5, this should hit all of @Andreas's test cases.

Looks like your regex is quite close, but the last statement in your non-capturing group, `(.*?)`, is going to regard the space after the open parenthesis as the "end" of its search, since it consumes as few characters as possible before it hits a space. Given that you know the function string will have spaces between the parenthesis, this regex seems to do the trick:

`(\S*?)=(?:"(.*?)"|(\S*?\(.*?\))|(\S*?))(?: |$)`

Critically, `\S` matches any non-whitespace character - since there's never going to be an example like `id=some val`, this is a good option to use, as it won't run over the parenthesis in functions. It also makes sure that the key name has no spaces, like `pare nt=val`.

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/xkRRsD/5)

Comment: Good catch. I'll look into that and see what I can find.

Comment: @Andreas Looks like I hit the cases you'd mentioned - see update.

Comment: Should it match for bad inputs? E.g. `a=b(5)c)` or `a="b"c`? I'd say no. Or at least only match the valid part `b(5)` and `"b"`. But, open to interpretation, so removing down-vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
([a-z]+)=(?:"(.*?)"|(.*?))(?:(?=[a-z]+?=)|$)
```

[image]

[`Regex Demo`](https://regex101.com/r/Z1uB8X/3)

Comment: Doesn't match `name=Evoke Sprite parent=EvokeObjects` according to rules. Rules specify that spaces in values can only appear when quoted or inside parenthesis.

Comment: @Andreas OP confirms there's no [`such case`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57080319/how-to-handle-spaces-in-values-if-you-use-spaces-as-a-delimiter-with-regex/57080574#comment100685476_57080319), anyways thanks for your feedback

Comment: I dont know if I'm allowed to ask this in the comments but I love that graphic you have there. How did you generate it?

Comment: @Flare this is what beauty of open source is people love sharing knowledge, this is generated using [`Regex visualizer`](https://jex.im/regulex)